# Naming inconsistencies in booktitle fields of BibTeX entries provided by IEEEXplore

Tags: citations, latex, bibtex

Why are the `booktitle` fields of BibTeX entries provided by IEEEXplore inconsistent in the following way:

```
@InProceedings{
...
booktitle={2009 International Conference on Reconfigurable Computing and FPGAs}, 
...
}
```

and

```
@InProceedings{
...
booktitle={Image Processing, 2004. ICIP '04. 2004 International Conference on},
...
}
```

Is there a specific reason for that? I've come across both styles in references. I think (if I understand https://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf correctly) the IEEE itself prefers the first variant. I do as well. What are the reasons others use variant two and why does IEEEXplore emit styles the IEEE does not encourage?

**Update:**

It seems like IEEEXplore is in fact simply emitting the names of the conferences. So the question becomes why the conference name is slightly changed almost every year (except for the year, obviously). See also http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/conhome.jsp?punumber=1000349 for an overview (click on "more history").

Comment: Why don't you edit (just position and few words) the booktitle field in your bibtex entry by yourself? That will solve the problem. Don't worry about what IEEE Xplore gives you while importing the entry. Make the consistency in your article.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the quality of Bibtex entries produced by the IEEE website is low. For instance, they do not properly escape capitals in titles nor diacritics in author names, and they do not identify names and surnames correctly. See for instance the Bibtex for [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7599632/) (found searching at random on their website), in which they did two of these mistakes and even forgot some HTML character codes in the title.

So it does not surprise me at all that there is also this inconsistency. I don't think they even bother checking, they just spew out whatever is in their database as a raw string. They put zero effort in them.

Comment: Does that mean that the names of the conferences did not change almost every year, just someone entered the conference name(s) wrongly? I guess I should the IEEE directly what the correct conference names are, they need to be 100% correct and consistent in my bibliography.

Comment: I would not consider a "name change" the one from *2009 International Conference on Peanuts* to *Peanuts, 2009 International Conference on*. It's just a different way to write the same name.